# Cluster-admin role in kube system

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I am new to k8s and I wonder what is the difference in terms of rbac between service account with role of cluster-admin in kube-system namespace and service account with role of cluster-admin in any other namespace. Thanks

Comment: Hello Revital Eres, if the answer provided by @coderanger has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`cluster-admin` is a ClusterRole. If you use a RoleBinding, it will apply to only the namespace that RoleBinding is in. If you use a ClusterRoleBinding it will apply to all namespaces.

Comment: Yes, I meant that in both cases I use ClusterRoleBinding to bind the cluster-admin role to the service accounts -- given that's the case does the rbac will be different for the sa in kube-system compared to the sa in other ns? Thanks

Comment: None, a ClusterRoleBinding is not in any namespace, it's a global-scoped object.